# Open multiple tabs in a loop and transfer different data to each tab's content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension works like this:

- a user presses `Run` button in the extension's popup
- the popup script collects an array of data from the active tab like article links, titles, etc
  ***Question #1:** How do I implement this?*
- multiple tabs are opened using the collected data in a loop
- a content script is injected into each opened tab
- each opened tab's content script should receive its own data from that array's element
  ***Question #2:** How do I implement this?*

Currently I'm using `chrome.storage.local` to store the entire array of collected data and would like to pass each content script the loop index variable so that the content script would read the correct element from `chrome.storage.local`.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description":"My article Extension",
   "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["model/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "run_at": "document_start",
     "matches": ["myurl"],
      "js": ["model/contentscript.js", "model/jquery_2.1.4.min.js"]
    }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "template/popup.html",
    "default_icon": "template/images/icon.png",
    "default_title": "Start copy articles"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16":"template/images/icon.png",
    "48":"template/images/icon.png",
    "128":"template/images/icon.png"
    },
 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "cookies"
 ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <title>Tapito Chrome extenstion</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Variable</p><br>
    <input type="text" value="" placehorlder="10" id="variable1" /><br>
    <button id="runScript">Run</button>
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="debugMode">

    </div>
</body>
```

**popup.js**, which doesn't collect the real data; a test articleArray is used

```
function StartPastingArticles(){
  var count = 3;

  // test array
  var articleArray = {
        articles: [
          {articleTitle: "title 1", articlePerex: "perex 1", articleAuthor: "author 1", articleDate: "date 1", articleUrl: "url 1"},
          {articleTitle: "title 2", articlePerex: "perex 2", articleAuthor: "author 2", articleDate: "date 2", articleUrl: "url 2"},
          {articleTitle: "title 3", articlePerex: "perex 3", articleAuthor: "author 3", articleDate: "date 3", articleUrl: "url 3"},
          {articleTitle: "title 4", articlePerex: "perex 4", articleAuthor: "author 4", articleDate: "date 4", articleUrl: "url 4"},
          {articleTitle: "title 5", articlePerex: "perex 5", articleAuthor: "author 5", articleDate: "date 5", articleUrl: "url 5"},
        ],
        options: [
          {time: '10', startDate: 'today'}
        ]
    };

        // actualy sending data via storage
        chrome.storage.local.set({'storageObjectName': articleArray}, function () {});

        var x = 1;
        while (x < count){
          chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'myurl'}, function(tab){
            openWindow(tab.id);
          });
          x++;
        }
}
    // open new window and run script
    function openWindow(tabId){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,{file:"contentscript.js"},function(){
        });
    }
 // callback for popup htm
document.getElementById("runScript").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    StartPastingArticles();
})
```

**contentscript.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   pasteData();
});
    var i;

/////////
function pasteData(){

        chrome.storage.local.get('storageObjectName', function (data) {
              chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){

            var testData = data;

            // article title
            document.getElementById('data_name').value = testData["storageObjectName"].articles[0]["articleTitle"];
            // article perex
            document.getElementById('data_perex').value = testData["storageObjectName"].articles[0]["articlePerex"];
            // article author
            document.getElementById('data_source').value = testData["storageObjectName"].articles[0]["articleAuthor"];
            // article url
            document.getElementById('data_url').value = testData["storageObjectName"].articles[0]["articleUrl"];
            // article date
            document.getElementById('data_valid_from').value = testData["storageObjectName"].articles[0]["articleDate"];

          });
}
```

Comment: Hello, i edited questing with all my code.

Comment: You don't need `chrome.storage.local` to pass the required data to content script. I can show you a simpler method via `sendMessage`, is it okay with you?

Comment: @wOxxOm sure thanks. i need also sent the X variable to new window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question has some issues:

1. the tabs are opened in popup.js before the `.set` callback is invoked (it is asynchronous as all the `chrome.` API callbacks)
2. the content script reads the data but never uses it because no message is sent to `onMessage` listener, thus its callback is never invoked.
3. both manifest.json defines the content script autoinjection rule AND popup.js injects it via `executeScript`.
4. for `executeScript` to work on tabs where the popup icon wasn't explicitly clicked, the urls should be declared in manifest.json's `"permissions"` key.

---

Actually for this task there's no need to save the data to `chrome.storage.local`.
Let's use simple messaging.

---

- **manifest.json**, assuming the content script should be injected only with `executeScript`:

  1. Remove `"content_script"` section.
  2. Add the permissions for `executeScript`:

     ```
     "permissions": [
         ................
         "*://possibleurl1/*",
         "http://possibleurl2/*",
         "https://possibleurl3/*",
     ]
     ```

     Or use `"<all_urls>"` to be able to inject the script on any site.
- **popup.js**, assuming all items of `articleArray` should be opened and the url is defined in `articleUrl` property:

  ```
  articleArray.articles.forEach(function(article) {
      chrome.tabs.create({url: article.articleUrl, active: false}, function(tab) {
          var tabId = tab.id;
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
              file: "contentscript.js",
              runAt: "document_start"
          }, function(result) {
              chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {action: "article", data: article});
          });
      });
  });
  ```

  So 1) a tab is created without activating it, 2) the content script is injected, 2) a message with the currently processed article data is sent to this tab.
- **contentscript.js**:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (msg.action == "article") {
          // make a local copy because msg will be garbage-collected
          var article = msg.data; 
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
              pasteData(article);
          });
      }
  });

  function pasteData(article) {
      document.getElementById('data_name').value = article.articleTitle;
      document.getElementById('data_perex').value = article.articlePerex;
      document.getElementById('data_source').value = article.articleAuthor;
      document.getElementById('data_url').value = article.articleUrl;
      document.getElementById('data_valid_from').value = article.articleDate;
  }
  ```

**To collect the data from the active tab** inject a content script with [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript):

- Make sure you have `"permissions": ["activeTab"]` or `["http://allowed.url/path/*"]` or `["<all_urls>"]` (try to avoid the latter as it's too permissive and the users won't like the warning that your extension can access and modify data on all sites they visit).
- Specify an inline code using `code:` parameter if it's short/simple
- Specify a separate content script file using `file:` parameter otherwise
- Make sure the last expression or statement in the code evaluates to a simple number/boolean or a string value (it will be passed to the callback), otherwise use `JSON.stringify(obj)`
- DOM elements can't be directly serialized; use `Array.map` or `innerHTML` or other methods to extract only the information you need
- The callback will receive an array of results, the first element corresponds to the main page, the others are for frames/iframes

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:" \
    JSON.stringify( \
        [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.article'), function(article) { \
            return { \
                title: article.querySelector('.title').textContent, \
                url: article.querySelector('a').href \
            }; \
        }) \
    )"
}, function(results) {
    var actualData = JSON.parse(results[0]);
    doSomething(actualData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Working perfectly!!! But i have the last question. How to combinate this script with the selecting data from "actual tab" ?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. i'll try apply this to my array, but still recived error: `Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Property 'function': Unexpected property.`

Comment: It could use a few comments, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: So thanks for this. I getting data correctly, but actualy i edited forEach script and getting in contentscript "undefined" values... my code: `.... function doSomething(data){
    var articleArray = data;

    articleArray.forEach(function(article) { .... `

Comment: New answer bellow... :-/

Comment: Hello, i find some issue in this script. When i open ( for example ) 20 tabs, i found that the script is not execute in all tabs. Without error, without log. Is there some way, how to delay the script, before previous tab is opened and data pasted? Thanks.

Comment: You should google first and try something before asking. I can only give you a generic answer: use `setTimeout`.

Comment: Sure, setTimeout is good fce, but i need check that, when data is pasting in tab and when yes, then open another.

Comment: You can use `.bind()` to pass the data to setTimeout. And once again: it's googlable.